# Output files not created running python script in background

Tags: python, csv, background-process

I'm very new to python and have over-extended myself.
I've hacked together a script which polls a JSON input stream from Twitter using cURL and converts it to a CSV file.

The script works perfectly when run at the $ prompt in foreground but does no more than create a 0 byte file when run in background using nohup - not even the CSV headers are written.

Here's a code snippet:

```
import pycurl, json, csv 
from datetime import *

outfile_path='/home/XXXX/twitter-feed.csv'
writer = csv.writer(open(outfile_path, 'wb'))

headers = ["user","timestamp","X","Y"]
writer.writerow(headers)
```

I'm guessing this is blindingly obvious to fix but any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: How do you start your script? Show the command lines pls.

Comment: I've tried both "/full_path/myscript.py &" and "nohup /full_path/myscript.py &"

Answer (score 0):

How do you start the script in the background? If you are not running it just by `python script.py &` then I would guess that there is a problem with path. Try adding

`#!/usr/bin/python`

to the first line of the script file, make the file executable by

`chmod +x script.py`

and run it by

`/full/path/to/script.py`

Also make sure that pycurl is in the [python's path](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) in the enviroment the script is running from.

If nothing helps (or even before trying) try to capture the script's output (it will print traceback if it "crashes"), i.e: `/full/path/to/script.py > /home/xxx/output.log 2>&1`

Comment: Thanks! I have the script/chmod suggestion covered, and the redirecting output generates no output. I'll explore the pythonpath suggestion

Comment: If there is no output then the pycurl probably is in the pythonpath, otherwise the ImportError would occur. Strange. Maybe the script doesn't run at all?

Comment: pycurl appears to be installed in /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7 which is in the PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all tips and help. I've got around the problem by launching the script using CRON which is working well.

Still no idea why the script doesn't like being launched in the background but since its working that can wait for another day.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem here is what @wjho mentioned. This may describe a solution: [CSVWriter not saving data to file the moment I write it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976711/csvwriter-not-saving-data-to-file-the-moment-i-write-it)

Add 'myfile.flush()' after writing your lines in python.

Answer (score -1):

I have got this problem now, actually, if you write more thing in the csv file , it would help,,,,  I think your python run in background and terminated by "kill + pid" ...
it seems that csv.write have a buffer stream,   if you kill the background process, then the stream gone,   you can write more thing in your csv file to check this,,,,

Comment: and the size of buffer stream is 16k,