# Scrapy write to csv without delay

Tags: python, scrapy

How can i configure the scrapy to write in csv without delay.

If i ran `scrapy crawl spider_1` and let say `spider_1` has an expected 200 items then the scrapy will going to write in csv but in by batch. I don't know where to configure this.

I tried the

```
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1

CONCURRENT_ITEMS = 1
```

but still it writes in csv file by 15+ batches.

Here is they way i tested it..

```
while sleep 2; do cat results/price.csv | wc -l; done;
```

result was

```
   0
  35
  35
  35
  35
  52
  52
  52
  52
  70
  70
```

Notice that it writes the first `32th` items then `20th` then `18th`.

What i want is that write the item right after it gets the data.
How can i do that?

Comment: scrapy don't make synchronous request. It send lots of request and wait for response. Therefore you don't get sequence output.

Comment: You may want to have a look at how [`CsvItemExporter`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/dfe6d3d59aa3de7a96c1883d0f3f576ba5994aa9/scrapy/exporters.py#L206) is implemented, esp. `.export_item()`.

Comment: I had similar problem. What I did I write all the data into mongodb and then write all data from there

Comment: @AnuragMisra actually your suggestion make sense. My current implementation was scrapy + django. The reason i don't want the delay because I want to show the incrementing number (csv row count) in angular. So with that, i can create a drf endpoint pointing to django model. Thanks

Comment: How does your pipeline be implemented?  Scrapy sends HTTP requests in order, but processes responses out of order. According to the framework diagram, the saving of items should be handled in pipeline. Make sure that your pipeline writes the item into file immediately, and remember to flush the cache.

Comment: @rojeeer, yes I implemented it in pipeline accordingly. I used `CsvItemExporter`. in spider_open , i do `spider_opened`. in `spider_closed` i do `self.exporter.finish_exporting()`. in `process_item` i do `self.exporter.export_item(item)` and also i save it in django database. When I run the crawler and check in django database, it is synchronous unlike in csv file.

Comment: @ji-ruh you can use `elasticsearch` it is a real-time database. so it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, when writing the item into the file, the item is not written to disk immediately, it is buffered unless the buffer is full or you flush the buffer. Since you use CsvItemExporter, which does not flush the buffer for each item, see [csvwriter does not save to file whay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976711/csvwriter-not-saving-data-to-file-why), you need to call flush if you do need this feature.

One option is that you can extend the CsvItemExporter and overwrite `export_item` function, e.g:

```
class MyCsvItemExporter(CsvItemExporter):
    def export_item(self, item):
        if self._headers_not_written:
            self._headers_not_written = False
            self._write_headers_and_set_fields_to_export(item)

        fields = self._get_serialized_fields(item, default_value='',
                                             include_empty=True)
        values = list(self._build_row(x for _, x in fields))
        self.csv_writer.writerow(values)
        #flush
        self.stream.flush()
```

I don't test the code yet. And also there is a topic about [python flush to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167494/how-often-does-python-flush-to-a-file) that is worth read.

Hope it is helpful.
Thanks