# Python multithreading output to CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, csv

I'm new to multithreading with python and I've just tried the following solution. The problem is that the output file is empty each time and I can't find the problem :

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import threading
csv_writer_lock = threading.Lock()

def get_data(searchKey):
  #do some data scraping
  l1.append(data)
  l2.append(data)
  l = l1 + l2
  with csv_writer_lock:
    with open("results.csv", mode="a") as f1:
      writer = csv.writer(f1, delimiter=",")
      writer.writerows(l)
    f1.close()
  return l

def set_up_threads(urls):
  try:
    
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        result = executor.map(get_data, urls["links"],timeout = 300)
  except Exception:
      print("Error")
  return result


df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
final = set_up_threads(df)
```

Somebody can point me in the direction of the error in this solution? thank you!

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976711/csvwriter-not-saving-data-to-file-the-moment-i-write-it ? (tl;dr make sure to call `flush` on the CSVWriter)

Comment: not sure why you're calling `f1.close()` since it's already called when you exit the `with` clause, other than that i see no reason for the csv to be empty

Comment: If you do a `print(l)` before trying to write it, does it contain any data? :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it using [@dtanabe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66342780/python-multithreading-output-to-csv-file?noredirect=1#comment117288665_66342780) trick, i have to add *flush*.