# Reading from a sensor and writing to a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a sensor which prints to my [COM4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_%28hardware_interface%29) port. I can read from this using `serial` like:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM4')
while True:
    if ser.in_waiting > 0:
        temp = ser.readline()
        print(temp)
```

Is there an efficient way to write this to a CSV file instead of printing to the console?

The problem I'm experiencing is if I stop the script midstream then the changes to the file seem to get thrown away, even if I include a step of writing the header in before the `while True` loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read and write CSV files with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python)

Comment: I should have been more specific, for my case when I have a live sensing that's being read from, if I stop the reading script then the file doesn't get updated and all changes are lost.

Comment: Ah, I see. You want to `flush()` the file after writing to it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976711/csvwriter-not-saving-data-to-file-the-moment-i-write-it

Comment: does this result in a significant slow-down? For example versus opening the file at each `readline()` and added the latest measurement?

Comment: File IO is expensive, so I expect it does. You could try it and see if it's too much for your liking. Alternatively, you could listen for `SIGINT`/`SIGTERM` and close the file before exiting when that happens. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499497/how-to-process-sigterm-signal-gracefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up, following Pranav Hosangadi's advice, handling the sigterm call manually as

```py
import serial
import signal

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    global interrupted
    interrupted = True


signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)
interrupted = False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ser = serial.Serial('COM4')
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        while True:
            if ser.in_waiting > 0:
                temp = ser.readline()
                f.write(temp)

            if interrupted:
                break
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM4')
while true:
  with open("csv-file-name.csv", 'w') as csvfile:
      writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
      if ser.in_waiting > 0:
        temp = ser.readline()
        writer.writerow(temp)
```

Check out [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) for more info.

Comment: Are you replacing 'import serial' with 'import csv'?

Comment: No, you should have both. Edited the code

Comment: This is what i had originally but if I stop this code abruptly then it's as if the file hasn't been touched. I chalked it up to improper closing of the file.

Comment: That is because the with clause closes the file once whatever is in it is done running, you should try switching the order and putting the with clause within the while loop. Edited the code.

Comment: then this is roughly equivalent to writing writer.flush() in the while loop as well? Except opening the file probably takes more effort than flushing to the file?

Comment: Yup, I would think it's pretty much the same, `flush()` is probably better programmatically though. Did you try the code?

Answer (score 0):

`readline` is blocking, so `in_waiting` is not necessary.

Instead of `print`, just use `write` to a file:

```
import serial

port = serial.Serial('COM4')
with open("output.csv", "w") as output:
    for line in port:
        output.write(line)
```